# pandas merge_asof with aggretion

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframes as follows.

```
admit = pd.DataFrame({"HN": ["001", "002", "001", "002"],
                      "dob": ["1999-05-25", "1979-08-12", "1999-05-25", "1979-08-12"],
                      "dateadm": ["2000-11-10", "2012-07-11", "2014-04-02", "2016-03-05"]})

admit["dateadm"] = pd.to_datetime(admit["dateadm"], format="%Y-%m-%d")

lab = pd.DataFrame({"HN": ["001", "002", "001", "002", "001"],
                    "labdate":["2000-11-11", "2012-07-13", "2000-11-15", "2016-03-05", "2014-04-02"],
                    "FPG": [100.0, 120.0, 95.5, 125.0, 99.0]})

lab["labdate"] = pd.to_datetime(lab["labdate"], format="%Y-%m-%d")
lab = lab.sort_values(by="labdate").reset_index(drop=True)
```

I would like to merge admit and lab together where taking the average of FPG of any labdate to the nearest dateadm.  Basicly the labdate for any dateadm should be the same or late date from such a dataadm.  I can think of this command

```
data = pd.merge_asof(admit, lab, left_on="dateadm", right_on="labdate", by="HN", direction="forward")
```

I got the returned output as follow.

```
 HN       dob        dateadm     labdate      FPG
001   1999-05-25   2000-11-10   2000-11-11   100.0
002   1979-08-12   2012-07-11   2012-07-13   120.0
001   1999-05-25   2014-04-02   2014-04-02    99.0
002   1979-08-12   2016-03-05   2016-03-05   125.0
```

However, the HN 001 with dateadm 2000-11-10 has 2 nearest labdate 2000-11-11 and 2000-11-15.  Therefore the FPG value in the first row should be the average between 100.0 and 95.5 which is equal to 97.75.  I think my command just take the first nearest date into account.  May I have your suggestion to get the desire output with the correct FPG value in the first row like this.

```
 HN       dob        dateadm     labdate      FPG
001   1999-05-25   2000-11-10   2000-11-11    97.75
002   1979-08-12   2012-07-11   2012-07-13   120.0
001   1999-05-25   2014-04-02   2014-04-02    99.0
002   1979-08-12   2016-03-05   2016-03-05   125.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I have found the solution for my question by just swapping left and right table then do group by as follow.

```
data = pd.merge_asof(lab, admit, left_on="labdate", right_on="dateadm", by="HN", direction="backward").groupby(["HN", "dob", "dateadm"]).agg({"FPG": "mean"}).reset_index()
```

Since one dateadm could have multiple labdate but the data granularity I want is by HN and dateadm.  So I can ignore the labdate in my desired output.